Add label to levels in ECharts Sankey graph
I am trying to customize an EChart Sankey and would like to add a label to the different levels.
For Example, I want to add the red text in this image.  What options do I need to change.
The levels documentation seems to imply that this would be correct option however there doesn't seem to be a way to add a label for the entire level.
https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-sankey.levels

Yes, level labels exist, but not the way you expect them, example.
A poor alternative (non-resposive) would be to use graphic.text and position them on top as labels.
